# Run a report for all possible input parameter values

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have a ssrs project made up of various reports and subreports, and when I preview it I simply select the parameter (unique ID) and it creates a report for this ID.

The parameter drop down is a list of about 100 different ID's and I just want to know how I can just make it create all 100 reports. I only know how to preview one at a time.

Do I need to set up a report server or something?

Comment: Is this SSRS report sql text base or store proc base? you can add `ALL` to the parameter >> when `ALL` select then ahow all records. Please show your SQL so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it. You don't provide much context or detail about your situation, but in general here are two options:

- Create a master report that has a dataset with all 100 ID's. Include a subreport (your actual report) inside a list and pass each ID as a parameter.
- Deploy the report to a report server and use data driven subscriptions.
- Programmatically generate the reports, for example by pulling a report from a report server for each ID, possibly via the web service endpoint or report server URLs.

Comment: I think thats what I was looking for. I guess I need to deploy to a report server and then use data driven subscriptions. Thanks.